# javascript function with parameters doesnt work with IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im calling the function **getStateCityZip** from inside a php function from line

```
$result = '<select name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'_new_id"'.$css_class.' '.$att.' onChange="getStateCityZip(this.value,`'.$userType.'`);"> ';
```

and the javascript function is

```
function getStateCityZip(customer_id,userType){
    var userType= String(userType);
    alert(customer_id + userType);
    $.post( "start_quote.php", { "action":"get_state_city_zip", 
    "customer_id" : customer_id})
    .done(function( data ) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( data );
    if (userType=='shipper'){
    $('#s_country').val(obj.billAddress.bill_country);
    $('#s_state').val(obj.billAddress.bill_state);
    $('#s_city').val(obj.billAddress.bill_city);
    $('#s_zip').val(obj.billAddress.bill_zip);
    }
}
```

This works fine on chrome but on IE it doesnt even give alert. If I were to remove the parameters from function definition and from the point where I call the function and hardcode the values inside the function defintion then it works just fine. In all the other cases I have tried it doesnt work for IE. All help will be appreciated

Comment: In your onchange, you use backticks in it, change these for single quotes, might not be the whole issue, but it may help

Comment: single quotes are used immediately before and after the back ticks. Also I did try using only single quotes and double and every combination of the three I could come up with

Comment: Right, I see now, try this instead; `onChange="getStateCityZip(this.value,\''.$userType.'\');"` you need to escape the quotes to add the variable

Comment: Yeah worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `'` instead of using backticks:

```
$result = '<select 
    name="'.$name.'" 
    id="'.$name.'_new_id"'.$css_class.' '.$att.' 
    onChange="getStateCityZip(this.value, \''.$userType.'\');"> ';
                                       // ^ here and here ^
```

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support template literals. You've used template literals around your `$userType` (the backticks).

In general, it's a bad idea to stuff strings into `onClick` attributes like this. But if you want to, you need to:

1. Ensure that all characters with special meaning in JavaScript string literals are escaped, **and**
2. Ensure that characters with special meaning in HTML are encoded (because the text in an `onClick` attribute — as with all attributes — is HTML text).

To do that:

```php
'...onChange="getStateCityZip(this.value, '.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($userType)).'...'
```

`json_encode` handles ensuring that a valid JavaScript string is output, and `htmlspecialchars` ensures that any HTML special characters (like `&`) are property encoded (as `&amp;` in the case of `&`). The characters your JavaScript function sees will be faithfully replicated, because the HTML parser consumes the encoded entities and emits the original character, and the JavaScript parser handles the escaped characters.